# Google Apps Script - setRichTextValue() exception possibly caused by for loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a script attached to a spreadsheet which amongst other things creates links to the worksheets in another spreadsheet.

I've used `newRichTextValue()` to make the links & stored them in an array ('ShtIDs')

The links are written into a range by looping over the array i.e

```
  for (var j = 0; j<=shtIDs.length; j++) {
    activeSht.getRange(2+j, 1, 1).setRichTextValue(shtIDs[j]);
  }
```

The script successfully writes the links into the spreadsheet and everything else I want it to do, but also throws an error i.e

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setRichTextValue on object SpreadsheetApp.Range.

When I change the above block of code (for debugging purposes) to

`var j=0;  activeSht.getRange(2+j, 1, 1).setRichTextValue(shtIDs[j]);`

there is no error warning.

Does anyone know how to prevent the Exception warning apparently caused by the for loop?

Tom

Comment: Try `for (var j = 0; j<shtIDs.length; j++) {
    activeSht.getRange(2+j, 1, 1).setRichTextValue(shtIDs[j]);
  }`

Comment: In an array the last index is length-1